# Como melhorar o desempenho de uma aplicação Android

Tags: android

Eu estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Android que recebe os dados de um  webservice (Json php).

A estrutura do projecto:
Para pegar os dados estou utilizando o asynctask, tenho um progressbar no preExecute e no proExecute  visualiza os dados. A classe do  'asynctask' é chamada no onCreate ().

Problemas:
A passagem dos dados  do webservice para o android demora muito e o progressebar também  e caso o utilizador vira a tela, reinicia a pesquisa, e isso torna a aplicação chata.

Como faço para resolver este problema ? 
Qual é a técnica utilizada nas aplicações como Whatssap ou o messanger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método que você escolher utilizar para carregar dados de um webservice numa thread em background não vai influenciar o desempenho. Com relação à perda do trabalho feito, isso é característica do AsyncTask que é uma das implementações mais simples de multitheading no Android e em geral é usado para processamentos mais rápidos (decodificação de imagem, por exemplo) e que não há problemas se o job for reinicializado. Para processamentos mais longos e que não dependam do estado da Activity, sugiro o uso de Loaders ou Services, de preferência esse último para o seu caso, pois são totalmente independentes do ciclo de vida da Activity.